# Mongoose - How to handle the result after using the populate method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I´m starting a work with mongoose. I have created 2 schemas . The second schema with reference to the first. The schemas are :

**User.js**

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {type: String, unique: true},
  first_name: String,
  middle_name: String,
  first_surname: String,
  second_surname: String,
  email: String,
  password: String
});
const UserModel = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

**Resource.js**

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const User = require('models/user');
const resourceSchema = new Schema({
  resourceType: String,
  creator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'},
  creationTime: String
});

const ResourceModel = mongoose.model('resource', resourceSchema);
```

Now I want to make a query to know the user who has created a resource. Here , I use the *Populate Method*,according to the documentation of mongoose [Documentacion about Populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). I have tried several options:

**Resources.js**

```
  ResourceModel.findOne({'_id': options.resourceId}).populate('creator').exec().then(resource => {
    log.info(resource.creator.username);
  });
```

The log.info return a undefined. If I change the code :

```
 ResourceModel.findOne({'_id': options.resourceId}).populate('creator').exec().then(resource => {
        log.info(resource.creator);
      });
```

The log.info return this:

```
$__: {
      "strictMode": true,
      "getters": {},
      "wasPopulated": true,
      "activePaths": {
        "paths": {
          "username": "init",
          "second_surname": "init",
          "password": "init",
          "middle_name": "init",
          "first_surname": "init",
          "first_name": "init",
          "email": "init",
          "_id": "init"
        },
        "states": {
          "ignore": {},
          "default": {},
          "init": {
            "username": true,
            "second_surname": true,
            "password": true,
            "middle_name": true,
            "first_surname": true,
            "first_name": true,
            "email": true,
            "_id": true
          },
          "modify": {},
          "require": {}
        },
        "stateNames": [
          "require",
          "modify",
          "init",
          "default",
          "ignore"
        ]
      },
      "emitter": {
        "domain": {
          "domain": null,
          "_events": {},
          "_eventsCount": 1,
          "members": [
            {
              "_readableState": {
                "objectMode": false,
                "highWaterMark": 16384,
                "buffer": [],
                "length": 0,
                "pipes": null,
                "pipesCount": 0,
                "flowing": true,
                "ended": true,
                "endEmitted": true,
                "reading": false,
                "sync": true,
                "needReadable": false,
                "emittedReadable": false,
                "readableListening": false,
                "resumeScheduled": false,
                "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
                "ranOut": false,
                "awaitDrain": 0,
                "readingMore": false,
                "decoder": null,
                "encoding": null
              },
              "readable": false,
              "domain": "[Circular]",
              "_events": {},
              "_eventsCount": 2,
              "socket": {
                "_connecting": false,
                "_hadError": false,
                "_handle": {
                  "bytesRead": 746,
                  "_externalStream": {},
                  "fd": 16,
                  "reading": true,
                  "owner": "[Circular]",
                  "onconnection": null,
                  "writeQueueSize": 0
                },
                "_parent": null,
                "_host": null,
                "_readableState": {
                  "objectMode": false,
                  "highWaterMark": 16384,
                  "buffer": [],
                  "length": 0,
                  "pipes": null,
                  "pipesCount": 0,
                  "flowing": true,
                  "ended": false,
                  "endEmitted": false,
                  "reading": true,
                  "sync": false,
                  "needReadable": true,
                  "emittedReadable": false,
                  "readableListening": false,
                  "resumeScheduled": false,
                  "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
                  "ranOut": false,
                  "awaitDrain": 0,
                  "readingMore": false,
                  "decoder": null,
                  "encoding": null
                },
                "readable": true,
                "domain": null,
                "_events": {
                  "end": [
                    null,
                    null
                  ],
                  "drain": [
                    null,
                    null
                  ],
                  "close": [
                    null,
                    null
                  ]
                },
                "_eventsCount": 10,
                "_writableState": {
                  "objectMode": false,
                  "highWaterMark": 16384,
                  "needDrain": false,
                  "ending": false,
                  "ended": false,
                  "finished": false,
                  "decodeStrings": false,
                  "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
                  "length": 0,
                  "writing": false,
                  "corked": 0,
                  "sync": true,
                  "bufferProcessing": false,
                  "writecb": null,
                  "writelen": 0,
                  "bufferedRequest": null,
                  "lastBufferedRequest": null,
                  "pendingcb": 0,
                  "prefinished": false,
                  "errorEmitted": false,
                  "bufferedRequestCount": 0,
                  "corkedRequestsFree": {
                    "next": null,
                    "entry": null
                  }
                },
                "writable": true,
                "allowHalfOpen": true,
                "destroyed": false,
                "_bytesDispatched": 0,
                "_sockname": null,
                "_pendingData": null,
                "_pendingEncoding": "",
                "server": {
                  "domain": null,
                  "_events": {
                    "connection": [
                      null,
                      null
                    ],
                    "clientError": [
                      null,
                      null
                    ]
                  },
                  "_eventsCount": 9,
                  "_connections": 1,
                  "_handle": {
                    "bytesRead": 0,
                    "_externalStream": {},
                    "fd": 15,
                    "reading": false,
                    "owner": "[Circular]",
                    "onread": null,
                    "writeQueueSize": 0
                  },
                  "_usingSlaves": false,
                  "_slaves": [],
                  "_unref": false,
                  "allowHalfOpen": true,
                  "pauseOnConnect": false,
                  "httpAllowHalfOpen": false,
                  "timeout": 120000,
                  "_pendingResponseData": 0,
                  "_connectionKey": "6::::3000"
                },
                "_server": "[Circular]",
                "_idleTimeout": 120000,
                "_idleNext": {
                  "_idleNext": "[Circular]",
                  "_idlePrev": "[Circular]"
                },
                "_idlePrev": "[Circular]",
                "_idleStart": 21855,
                "parser": {
                  "_headers": [],
                  "_url": "",
                  "_consumed": true,
                  "socket": "[Circular]",
                  "incoming": "[Circular]",
                  "outgoing": null,
                  "maxHeaderPairs": 2000
                },
                "_paused": false,
                "_consuming": true,
                "_httpMessage": {
                  "domain": "[Circular]",
                  "_events": {},
                  "_eventsCount": 1,
                  "output": [],
                  "outputEncodings": [],
                  "outputCallbacks": [],
                  "outputSize": 0,
                  "writable": true,
                  "_last": false,
                  "chunkedEncoding": false,
                  "shouldKeepAlive": true,
                  "useChunkedEncodingByDefault": true,
                  "sendDate": true,
                  "_removedHeader": {},
                  "_contentLength": null,
                  "_hasBody": true,
                  "_trailer": "",
                  "finished": false,
                  "_headerSent": false,
                  "socket": "[Circular]",
                  "connection": "[Circular]",
                  "_header": null,
                  "_headers": null,
                  "_headerNames": {},
                  "log": {
                    "domain": null,
                    "_events": {},
                    "_eventsCount": 0,
                    "_level": 30,
                    "streams": [
                      {
                        "type": "stream",
                        "stream": {
                          "_connecting": false,
                          "_hadError": false,
                          "_handle": {
                            "bytesRead": 0,
                            "_externalStream": {},
                            "fd": 1,
                            "writeQueueSize": 0,
                            "owner": "[Circular]"
                          },
                          "_parent": null,
                          "_host": null,
                          "_readableState": {
                            "objectMode": false,
                            "highWaterMark": 16384,
                            "buffer": [],
                            "length": 0,
                            "pipes": null,
                            "pipesCount": 0,
                            "flowing": null,
                            "ended": false,
                            "endEmitted": false,
                            "reading": false,
                            "sync": true,
                            "needReadable": false,
                            "emittedReadable": false,
                            "readableListening": false,
                            "resumeScheduled": false,
                            "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
                            "ranOut": false,
                            "awaitDrain": 0,
                            "readingMore": false,
                            "decoder": null,
                            "encoding": null
                          },
                          "readable": false,
                          "domain": null,
                          "_events": {},
                          "_eventsCount": 3,
                          "_writableState": {
                            "objectMode": false,
                            "highWaterMark": 16384,
                            "needDrain": false,
                            "ending": false,
                            "ended": false,
                            "finished": false,
                            "decodeStrings": false,
                            "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
                            "length": 0,
                            "writing": false,
                            "corked": 0,
                            "sync": false,
                            "bufferProcessing": false,
                            "writecb": null,
                            "writelen": 0,
                            "bufferedRequest": null,
                            "lastBufferedRequest": null,
                            "pendingcb": 0,
                            "prefinished": false,
                            "errorEmitted": false,
                            "bufferedRequestCount": 0,
                            "corkedRequestsFree": {
                              "next": null,
                              "entry": null
                            }
                          },
                          "writable": true,
                          "allowHalfOpen": false,
                          "destroyed": false,
                          "_bytesDispatched": 766,
                          "_sockname": null,
                          "_writev": null,
                          "_pendingData": null,
                          "_pendingEncoding": "",
                          "server": null,
                          "_server": null,
                          "_type": "pipe",
                          "fd": 1,
                          "_isStdio": true
                        },
                        "raw": false,
                        "level": 30,
                        "closeOnExit": false
                      }
                    ],
                    "serializers": null,
                    "src": false,
                    "fields": {
                      "name": "hommer-ml",
                      "module": "log",
                      "hostname": "sd-dev",
                      "pid": 14028
                    }
                  },
                  "_time": 1471589378213,
                  "acceptable": [
                    "application/json",
                    "text/plain",
                    "application/octet-stream",
                    "application/javascript"
                  ],
                  "formatters": {},
                  "req": "[Circular]",
                  "serverName": "hommer-ml",
                  "methods": [
                    "GET"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "connection": "[Circular]",
              "httpVersionMajor": 1,
              "httpVersionMinor": 1,
              "httpVersion": "1.1",
              "complete": true,
              "headers": {
                "host": "localhost:3000",
                "authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmaXJzdF9uYW1lIjoiamVzdXMiLCJtaWRkbGVfbmFtZSI6Implc3VzIiwiZmlyc3Rfc3VybmFtZSI6ImNhcm1vbmEiLCJpZCI6IjU3OTcyNzQ4NjkxZmZhNmY0MWFlYWQ4YyIsImhvc3QiOiIxMC4wLjIuMiIsImlhdCI6MTQ3MDEyNjIyMH0._qU7nBVrWb0m5Q__dA8FCgjaKp47Nnv1zB9rzjn4CNY",
                "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36",
                "content-type": "application/json",
                "accept": "*/*",
                "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
                "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6",
                "x-forwarded-for": "10.0.2.2",
                "x-forwarded-host": "localhost:8080",
                "x-forwarded-server": "127.0.1.1",
                "connection": "Keep-Alive"
              },
              "rawHeaders": [
                "Host",
                "localhost:3000",
                "Authorization",
                "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmaXJzdF9uYW1lIjoiamVzdXMiLCJtaWRkbGVfbmFtZSI6Implc3VzIiwiZmlyc3Rfc3VybmFtZSI6ImNhcm1vbmEiLCJpZCI6IjU3OTcyNzQ4NjkxZmZhNmY0MWFlYWQ4YyIsImhvc3QiOiIxMC4wLjIuMiIsImlhdCI6MTQ3MDEyNjIyMH0._qU7nBVrWb0m5Q__dA8FCgjaKp47Nnv1zB9rzjn4CNY",
                "User-Agent",
                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36",
                "Content-Type",
                "application/json",
                "Accept",
                "*/*",
                "Accept-Encoding",
                "gzip, deflate, sdch",
                "Accept-Language",
                "en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6",
                "X-Forwarded-For",
                "10.0.2.2",
                "X-Forwarded-Host",
                "localhost:8080",
                "X-Forwarded-Server",
                "127.0.1.1",
                "Connection",
                "Keep-Alive"
              ],
              "trailers": {},
              "rawTrailers": [],
              "upgrade": false,
              "url": "/api/authorizations/57b566ee593e745b25008983/permission",
              "method": "GET",
              "statusCode": null,
              "statusMessage": null,
              "client": "[Circular]",
              "_consuming": true,
              "_dumped": false,
              "log": {
                "domain": "[Circular]",
                "_events": {},
                "_eventsCount": 0,
                "_level": 30,
                "streams": [
                  {
                    "type": "stream",
                    "stream": "[Circular]",
                    "raw": false,
                    "level": 30,
                    "closeOnExit": false
                  }
                ],
                "serializers": null,
                "src": false,
                "fields": {
                  "name": "hommer-ml",
                  "module": "log",
                  "hostname": "sd-dev",
                  "pid": 14028,
                  "req_id": "cb1702ef-2c55-49bb-9cbd-ad5e65eee8f8",
                  "action": "GET",
                  "ip": "10.0.2.2"
                }
              },
              "_time": 1471589378213,
              "serverName": "hommer-ml",
              "_version": "*",
              "_url": {
                "protocol": null,
                "slashes": null,
                "auth": null,
                "host": null,
                "port": null,
                "hostname": null,
                "hash": null,
                "search": null,
                "query": null,
                "pathname": "/api/authorizations/57b566ee593e745b25008983/permission",
                "path": "/api/authorizations/57b566ee593e745b25008983/permission",
                "href": "/api/authorizations/57b566ee593e745b25008983/permission"
              },
              "_cacheURL": "/api/authorizations/57b566ee593e745b25008983/permission",
              "params": {
                "resource_id": "57b566ee593e745b25008983"
              },
              "context": "[Circular]",
              "route": {
                "path": "api/authorizations/:resource_id/permission",
                "method": "GET",
                "versions": [],
                "name": "getapiauthorizationsresource_idpermission"
              },
              "_dtraceId": 1,
              "_anonFuncCount": 2,
              "_currentRoute": "getapiauthorizationsresource_idpermission",
              "_currentHandler": "handler-1",
              "_timerMap": {
                "bunyan": [
                  0,
                  297414
                ],
                "parseQueryString": [
                  0,
                  115094
                ],
                "readBody": [
                  0,
                  1285054
                ],
                "parseBody": [
                  0,
                  684934
                ],
                "logContext": [
                  0,
                  1316491
                ],
                "handler-0": [
                  0,
                  2723801
                ],
                "handler-1": [
                  970057,
                  332862660
                ]
              },
              "_id": "cb1702ef-2c55-49bb-9cbd-ad5e65eee8f8",
              "timers": [
                {
                  "name": "bunyan",
                  "time": "[Circular]"
                },
                {
                  "name": "parseQueryString",
                  "time": "[Circular]"
                },
                {
                  "name": "readBody",
                  "time": "[Circular]"
                },
                {
                  "name": "parseBody",
                  "time": "[Circular]"
                },
                {
                  "name": "logContext",
                  "time": "[Circular]"
                },
                {
                  "name": "handler-0",
                  "time": "[Circular]"
                }
              ],
              "query": {},
              "_clen": false,
              "_contentType": "application/json",
              "body": "",
              "user": {
                "first_name": "jesus",
                "middle_name": "jesus",
                "first_surname": "carmona",
                "id": "57972748691ffa6f41aead8c",
                "host": "10.0.2.2",
                "iat": 1470126220
              }
            },
            "[Circular]"
          ]
        },
        "_events": {},
        "_eventsCount": 0,
        "_maxListeners": 0
      }
    }
    --
    _doc: {
      "username": "jecargar",
      "second_surname": "garcia",
      "password": "test",
      "middle_name": "jesus",
      "first_surname": "gonzalez",
      "first_name": "juan",
      "email": "email@email.com",
      "_id": "57972748691ffa6f41aead8c"
    }
    --
    _pres: {
      "$__original_save": [
        null,
        null
      ]
    }
    --
    _posts: {
      "$__original_save": []
    }
```

According to the above result, acceding to *._doc.creator*, we can find the attributes of the creator of the resource. Finally, I use this:

```
 ResourceModel.findOne({'_id': options.resourceId}).populate('creator').exec().then(resource => {
    log.info(resource.creator._doc.username);
  });
```

The log.info show the creator´s username but I do not know if it's the right way to use Populate method.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an error thrown if you use:

```js
ResourceModel.findOne({_id : options.resourceId})
             .populate('creator')
             .exec((error, resource) => {
                   if (error) throw error;
                   console.log(resource._id);
                   console.log(resource.creator._id);
                   console.log(resource.creator.username);
              });
```

Is there an export in your models? I'm not sure if  you need it, but I use something like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var OtherModel = require('./OtherModel.js');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
    linkedField: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'other'}
});
```

and then I use `User.findOne({_id : ...` in my routes

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I  thrown the error but I get the same result.
NOTE: I am using _Promises_

Comment: Ok and what will happen if you remove the .then function only for a quick testing? Because I only use exec and it works as expected.. What kind of promises do you use ? The ES6 native promise `mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;` ?

Comment: Oh sorry me, I was handling the _resource, error_  inside _.then_ . Now this works.

Answer (score 0):

handle response this way

```
 ResourceModel.findOne({
     '_id': options.resourceId
 })
 .populate('creator')
 .exec(function(err, res) {
     console.log(err)
     console.log(res)

 })
```